# CentOS doesn't boot with "A stop job is running for Security Auditing Service" message

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, audit, auditd

CentOS prints the following during boot

```
[ ***  ] A stop job is running for Security Auditing Service (9s / 1min 30s)
```

and then switches into the single user mode.

Comment: I had a problem and it wasn't googleable, so here is the problem and the solution for future generations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in `/etc/audit/auditd.conf` - see [man 5 auditd.conf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/auditd.conf.5.html)

In the case of not enough memory (for audit logs), it was set to switch the server into the single user mode:

```
space_left_action = SINGLE
admin_space_left_action = SINGLE
```

The fix was to tweak the values of `space_left` and `admin_space_left` or to revert the original values of:

```
space_left_action = SYSLOG
admin_space_left_action = SUSPEND
```